# Deferring a Google Maps API callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-deferred

I am currently building a widget that is using the google maps api v3. The setup process of it looks like that:

1. inject jQuery
2. inject html structure
3. inject googlemaps api (that only loads a bootstrap .js file that, again, loads the actual main.js) && load map data
4. as soon as the googlemaps api is loaded setup the basic map
5. as soon as the map data is loaded apply that on the map (e.g. set markers)

My Problem is that i can set a [callback](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch) method to fire when the google api finished loading. I would like to start loading my data and as soon as the map has loaded and the data request succeeded (or failed) apply the data. I'm using [jQuery's Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), the code looks something like that:

The Main Part:

```
jQuery.when(
    fn.getData()
)
.then(function(resolvedArgs) {
    gmap.setData(resolvedArgs['data']);
    gmap.addMarkerOverlay();
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    var message = textStatus + ': loading data';
    fn.showInfoBox(message);
});
```

The GoogleMaps Part (same origin policy workaround, this is the basic return from the function responsible for loading external scripts):

```
return jQuery.Deferred(function(deferred) {
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag['type'] = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag['src'] = 'googlemapsapiurl&callback=setupGoogleMap';
    scriptTag['async'] = true;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
    scriptTag['onload'] = scriptTag['onreadystatechange'] = function() {
        if (!this.readyState || this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === 'complete') {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    };
}).promise();
```

The second GoogleMaps Part:

```
var setupGoogleMap = function() {
    jQuery('.container').trigger('googleMapsReady');
};
```

and...

```
jQuery('.container').on('googleMapsReady', function(event) {
    fn.setupGoogleMap();
});
```

I don't know where to put the google api request since it's kind of a two-step loading process on google's end. Maybe I can prevent jQuery Deferred's default success resolve()-call and resolve the Deferred in the google api callback method instead? Any ideas?

Comment: I need more detail. I can't see what problem you need help solving exactly. I'm not sure if I need to see more code or need it explained better.